# Batch script to re-size JPEGs in music folder to 350x350 and delete unwanted files

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I currently use a script to rename music folders from eg. `Taylor Swift - 1989` to a new folder `Taylor Swift` with a subfolder `1989` with all files moved into it.

I've also added a rename line to change the the `.jpg` file to be renamed `Folder` which works a treat.

I'd like to know if it's possible to resize/scale that `.jpg` file to a smaller size of 350x350 instead of me doing it through the old Microsoft Office 2010 picture program.

Lastly, I can't work out how to delete unwanted files, these being `.log`, `.txt`, `.info`

If I could get this all on the same batch script, that would be amazing.

This is what I currently use :

```
@echo off & cd /d "%~dp0"

for /f delims^= %%i in =;(' dir /a:-a /b "* - *"
    ');= do for /f usebackq^tokens^=1*delims^=-^" %%G in =;(`
         set /p "'=%%~nxi"^<nul `);= do call %:^) "%%~G" "%%~H" "%%~dpnxi"

for /r /d %%i in (*)do if exist "%%~fi\*.jpg" for /f tokens^=* %%I in (
'%__APPDIR__%where.exe "%%~i:*.jpg"')do ren "%%~fI" "Folder.jpg"

%:^)
if not "%~1" == "" =;(
     set "_dir=%~1" & set "_sub=%~2"
     call rename "%~3" "%%_sub:~1%%"
     call mkdir "%cd%\%%_dir:~0,-1%%"
     call move "%%_sub:~1%%" "%%_dir:~0,-1%%" 
     );= & exit /b
```

Comment: What program would you like to use to resize the image? Command line can't do that by itself you would need a third party editing tool like irfranview, ffmpeg or image magick....

Comment: Oh good question.. the only program I use to re-size pictures is as stated, Window office picture manager 2010, I am not opposed to downloading and using one of those other 3 if office won't do it

Comment: What's with all those semicolons in the code?

Comment: @Shane Cusack if this program "Window office picture manager 2010" has switches to automate you can use it. Would be something like: officePicMan.exe "folder.jpg" /s 350x350, otherwhise you would have to use something else.

Comment: I'm afraid you question is going to be closed, already 2 down votes...

Comment: I want HELP.. not to close me down.. there's 2 parts to this, If you can't help with the re-size, help with the delete of unwanted files. but as I said, I'd use one of the othger 3 programs to help with the re-size, just help/show me how..

Comment: lo-ol part of this code is yours from previous help.. you have always been outstanding..  I don't believe I was given help on this matter from Ricardo.. he asked what program.. I answered, and also said I'd use another program.. then he said the post would be closeed.. If it can't be done.. just say.. SAY what works and I'll try it.

Comment: Look I'm no genius with this stuff, I've tried to modify and work things out, I've tried to streamline what I'm doing, I appreciate all the help, But I can keep doing what I'm doing if it's not possible.. Also I'm not 100% on the rules of including links from present links, lo-ol I mentioned you in the post coz you seem to be the best

Comment: I know |o-o| and wrote him an email with the link of this topic, if he has time he's probably looking into it. I myself am having some difficulty to understand the script because of the wierd symbols it has. If I have time I try to make a new one later. By the way if you want to draw someone's attantion you should use @nickname....

Comment: As @RicardoBohner states, there are a number of free and commercial applications that include batch operations, with GUI, such as IrfanView. For example that app can resize pictures, set a maximum or minimum for horizontal and vertical size, resize proportionately or with distortion, etc. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41520/whats-a-good-program-to-batch-resize-100-000-jpg-images/41705, for example (BTW, IView is native Windows, but runs well under wine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this works, I hope it is as your intended. I filled the batch code with comments to explain what every command does (or most of them). Test this only on a copy to see if it works as expected. You have to have Image magick installed for the resize and rename to Folder.jpg option to work.

```
@echo off

:: set here the rootfolder where the music folders are:
set RootFolder=%userprofile%\desktop\music

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b "%RootFolder%\*-*"') do for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %%b in ("%%~a") do (
                                                                                                         set "OriginalName=%%~a"
                                                                                                         set "FolderPart1=%%~b"
                                                                                                         set "FolderPart2=%%~c"
                                                                                                         call :Edit "%%~b" "%%~c"
                                                                                                        )
echo This is the end....
exit


:Edit
:: checks and removes if there are white spaces in front and back of new folder names:
if "%FolderPart1:~-1%"==" " (set "FolderPart1=%FolderPart1:~0,-1%" & goto :Edit)
if "%FolderPart2:~0,1%"==" " (set "FolderPart2=%FolderPart2:~1%" & goto :Edit)

:: deletes log txt and info files:
del /q "%RootFolder%\%OriginalName%\*.log"
del /q "%RootFolder%\%OriginalName%\*.txt"
del /q "%RootFolder%\%OriginalName%\*.info"

:: uses image magick to create a resized copy named Folder.jpg of a jpg file inside the original folder: 
magick "%RootFolder%\%OriginalName%\*.jpg" -resize 350x350 "%RootFolder%\%OriginalName%\Folder.jpg"

:: deletes all jpg files except Folder.jpg inside the original folder:
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "%RootFolder%\%OriginalName%\*.jpg" ^|find /i /v "Folder.jpg"') do del /q "%RootFolder%\%OriginalName%\%%~a"

:: Creates a new folder from the part before the hifen "-" in the original folder:
if not exist "%RootFolder%\%FolderPart1%" md "%RootFolder%\%FolderPart1%"

:: moves and renames the original folder to the second part or the original foldername (behind the hifen):
move "%RootFolder%\%OriginalName%" "%RootFolder%\%FolderPart1%\%FolderPart2%"
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Wow. Thankyou very much Ricardo. This does everything I asked for, gonna save me soo much time.